# api directory not found in magento

Tags: magento

I am new to magento and trying it out.. I have successfully installed magento. Created a user to access magento API’s. 
But I face problem when I try to establish the connection through SOAP.

`$proxy = new SoapClient(’http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/soap/?wsdl’);`

I found that "api" directory is not found in magento folder. After installing magento I have enabled the "soap extension" (extension=php_soap.dll) in php.ini

Should I re-install magento now?

My PHP version 5.3.4

Thanks, 
Karthik

Comment: Is this a WAMP or LAMP stack?  Have you created API users/roles within Magento's backend?

Comment: It is WAMP, I have Create API roles in backend!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read over this tutorial:

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/629-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-1

Also, the directory ... /api/soap/ is not going to exist as it is apart of the rewrite to index.php.